# Matrix Ring over Semisimple Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a semisimple ring, and let $M_n(R)$ denote the ring of $n \times n$ matrices over $R$. I am trying to show that $M_n(R)$ is semisimple.

So far, I have that $M_n(R) = \bigoplus_i L_i$, where $L_i$ is the ideal of matrices with all $0$ entries outside the $i$-th column. Since the $L_i$ are minimal, we have that $M_n(R)$ is semisimple.

But this doesn't seem right, since  I haven't used the assumption that $R$ is semisimple - this "proof" would work for any ring $R$. Where is the mistake in my proof?

Comment: Your Ls are not simple modules. For example, if $R=k\times k$, a direct product of two fields, and $n=1$, your $L_1$ is isomorphic to $R$ itself, which is obviously not simple.

Comment: When in doubt, **always** look at extreme cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following two simple observations together with Wedderburn's theorem.

- A ring of matrices over the ring of matrices over a ring R is simply a ring of (larger) matrices over R.
- A ring of matrices over a direct product of rings is just the direct product of the matrix rings of the factors.

Comment: I thought about this approach, but got hung up on your second point - is it difficult to show that the matrix ring of the direct product is the direct product of the matrix rings of the factors?

Comment: Both points are very easy. I jthe case of direct products, the obvious map is an isomorphism!

Answer (score 0):

$L_i$ are isomorphic to free modules over $R$ which can be written as the direct sum of simple submodules since $R$ is semisimple. You need the assumption that $R$ is semisimple since $L_i$ are not simple modules.

Comment: What next?. May you provide more steps please?.